# Is there a way we can enhance the below query in Oracle 12C

Tags: sql, oracle12c

Is there anyway we can optimize the below query in Oracle 12c to give faster result.

TAB_C - is the main table -2947109424 count and we have index in place on TAB_C(act_id).But still it is taking 3 hours to run in production.

```
SELECT ta.email_addr_id 
                       , ta.email_addr 
                        , SUBSTR(ta.email_addr, INSTR(ta.email_addr, '@') + 1,  
                           INSTR(ta.email_addr, '.', -1) - INSTR(ta.email_addr, '@') 
                           - 1) AS email_domain
                         , mtr.max_email_response_date  
                         , ta.add_date  
                         , net.num_12mons 
                         , net.num_3mons 
                          , net.num_6mons 
                          , net.num_9mons 
                         , ta.hard_bounce_ind 
                         , ta.email_addr_text_att_02 AS preference_birth_date 
                          ,ta.source AS source 
                     FROM Tab_A ta 
                     LEFT JOIN ( 
                         SELECT tr.email_addr_id 
                             , tcX(tr.email_response_date) AS max_email_response_date  
                         FROM Tab_B tr 
                         where tr.email_response_date = 'NEW' 
                             AND tr.update_source <> 'EXP_EVENT' 
                         GROUP BY tr.email_addr_id 
                     ) mtr  
                     ON ta.email_addr_id = mtr.email_addr_id 
                     LEFT JOIN ( 
                         SELECT tc.email_addr_id 
                             , COUNT(DISTINCT tc.m_act_id) AS num_12mons 
                             , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD')  
                                 > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 90) 
                                 THEN tc.m_act_id ELSE NULL END) AS num_3mons 
                              , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD')  
                                  > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 180) 
                                  THEN tc.m_act_id ELSE NULL END) AS num_6mons 
                              , COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD')  
                                  > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 270) 
                                  THEN tc.m_act_id ELSE NULL END) AS num_9mons 
                         FROM Tab_C tc     
                         INNtr JOIN act a 
                         ON tc.act_id = a.act_id 
                         where a.channel_code IN ('FM','RM') 
                             AND ROUND(tc.outbound_date, 'DD') > (ROUND(sysdate, 'DD') - 365) 
                         GROUP BY tc.email_addr_id 
                     ) net 
                     ON ta.email_addr_id = net.email_addr_id 
                     where ta.email_addr_id <> 0 ;
```

Any insight will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "-2947109424" - why is your count value negative?

Comment: Post your query's execution plan.

Comment: its not negative TAB_C - count - 2947109424

Comment: Without the query plan we can't get very far. With that said, it is quite possible that the index won't be very useful. You have an inner join between `Tab_C` and `act` on `act_id`, which joins 3 billion rows of `Tab_C` with ? rows of `act`. The only time an index will help is if `act` has few rows. At some point, the many index accesses will be more expensive than a full table scan and hash join. Post the plan.

Comment: Can we re-write the 'DISTINCT' columns in any alternative way(without using DISTINCT function), as DISTINCT is making the query very slow.